# Unable to check the radio button and get the value of radio button

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to fetch data from my MongoDB Database and trying to display the data using React in the Database i have 4 Attributes named Ques,Ques_type,Ans and Options in which option is an array now i want to create radio buttons for all the options while mapping from the database. I am doing it like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import {Form,Radio,} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';





export default class QuestionList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {questions:[],
          answer:''}

    }

    handleOptionChange(e){
      this.setState({
        answer: e.target.value
      });
    }

    handleFormSubmit (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log('You have selected:', this.state.answer);
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/question/')
        .then(respose =>{
            this.setState({questions:respose.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    };



    questionList() {

        return this.state.questions.map(currentquestion => {

          return(
            <Form onSubmit ={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <Form.Field>
         <h3>Q.  {currentquestion.ques}</h3>
          <h6>Correct Answer is {currentquestion.ans} </h6>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label={currentquestion.options[0]}
            name='radioGroup'
            value ={currentquestion.options[0]}
            checked = {this.state.answer === currentquestion.options[0]}
            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}

          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label={currentquestion.options[1]}
            name='radioGroup'
            value ={currentquestion.options[1]}
            checked = {this.state.answer === currentquestion.options[1]}
            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}

          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label={currentquestion.options[2]}
            name='radioGroup'
            value = {currentquestion.options[2]}
            checked = {this.state.answer === currentquestion.options[2]}
            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}

          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label={currentquestion.options[3]}
            name='radioGroup'
            value={currentquestion.options[3]}
            checked = {this.state.answer === currentquestion.options[3]}
            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}

          />
        </Form.Field>

        <button type ="submit" class="ui button" >Submit Answer</button>
        <hr />

      </Form>

          );
        })
      }



  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Questions</h2>
        <hr />
        <hr />
        <p>{ this.questionList() } </p>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

but when i try to select the radio button i am unable to check them that means i am not able to store anything in answer state. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem . Instead of using radio use chekcbox of semantic-ui-react of Checkboxradiogroup. You can find it here https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/#types-radio-group

```
<Checkbox
            label={currentquestion.options[0]}
            name='checkboxRadioGroup'
            id = {currentquestion._id}
            value ={currentquestion.options[0]}
            checked = {this.state.value === currentquestion.options[0]}
            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}

          />
```